# Ranking based on weight for multiple variables and objectives

Tags: ranking, weighted-sampling, weighted-mean, weighted-data

First of all, I know very little about statistics. I need help ranking a set of multiple solutions (about 138 solutions) based on three objectives. I work on the architectural design field, I analyzed 138 different windows and shading devices to improve three objectives a) increase lighting levels b) decrease temperature c) increase lighting uniformity ratio. upon finishing my lighting simulation, I recorded all configurations in an excel sheet (an example is shown in the attached image). I need to rank these configurations based on maximized Value on column C, minimized value on column D, and maximized[image] value on column E. and by the way top test these 138 configurations I had a to change 1 variable for 6 of them and 4 variables for 96 of them, and 6 variables for the rest. ( I have all the variables and objectives recorded in an excel sheet too.)

Comment: Perhaps I can rank them on a Pareto Frontier in Excel, can someone explain how do I do that in Excel?

Comment: I have to mention that column C the numbers are from 35 to 95. the higher the better. for column D the numbers range from 22 to 32 , the lower the better. the numbers in column E are from .2 to .4, the higher the better. All three scores are equally important. All the configurations are compared against a base-case ( which is in raw 2).